# Email form responses, but do not include blank responses

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-forms

So I am using a script i found on line to send an email everytime a Google Form is completed, which includes the data in the form via a Google Sheet.

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{    
  var email = “email@address.com”; 

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var message = "A new travel request has been submitted.";
  var subject = "New Travel Justification Request: ";

  for(var i in headers) 
    message += headers[i] + ': '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";     

  subject += e.namedValues[headers[2]].toString() + " - starts " + e.namedValues[headers[15]].toString();

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

  // Based off of a script originally posted by Amit Agarwal - www.labnol.org
  // Credit to Henrique Abreu for fixing the sort order
}
```

It works well, but I want it to exclude the headers for empty cells, as not all parts of the form require completion.

I know very little, so all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the original [Google Form script](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/) to not include fields that are empty. You can add a simple condition in the for loop:

```
for(var i in headers) {
  if ( e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() != "") {
     message += headers[i] + ': '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";  
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked well, thanks.

I now want to adjust it to send to 2 email addresses. Is that possible? If so, how?

Thanks again.

Comment: From [ctrlq.org](http://ctrlq.org/help/60-send-google-form-response-to-multiple-recipients): Replace the first line: `var email = "a@b.com, b@c.com";`